# Qualitative understanding of Fisher Information

Tags: fisher-information

I'm struggling with understanding what Fisher Information is. Here is my thought process.

We begin with the PDF $f(x)$ of some distribution. Let's assume we are dealing with a continuous case on the real line. Then, in the framework of the statistics class, we say that our distribution also depends on some parameter $\theta$, which is unknown. So, our PDF becomes a function of two parameters - $f(x,\theta)$.

We observe an experiment. We get some results $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$, that are i.i.d. We consider the joint PDF function $g(\bar X,\theta)=f(X_1,\theta)f(X_2,\theta)...f(X_n,\theta)$.

With the experiment result known, our function $g$ becomes a function of only one variable $\theta$ and is denoted by $g(\theta|\bar X)$. And it is now called the likelihood function.

We are now interested in knowing how much this particular experiment result is informative. The quantity assigned is the Fisher Information, that is defined by:

$I(\theta)=E_{\theta} [\frac{d}{d\theta}(ln(g(\theta |\bar X))^2]$.

**First thing i don't understand is the role of the function $ln$ here**. Taking it as it is, my further understanding is following:

We consider the graph of the likelihood function $g(\theta)$. Then, we consider the slope of this function. Because, the bigger the slope is, the bigger the difference between the likelihood function values on close values of $\theta$ will be, and we will be able to locate $\theta$ more precisely (hence, "more information"). Now, we don't know the exact value of $\theta$, so we would like to average that slope value over all domain of $\theta$. We will also have to account for the fact that different values of $\theta$ can appear with different probabilities. The function of expected value $E$, then, is exactly what we need.

We arrive at this: $E_{\theta} [\frac{d}{d\theta}(ln(g(\theta |\bar X))]$=$\int _{\Theta} {\frac{d}{dt}(ln(g(t |\bar X))\theta(t)dt}$, where $\theta (t)$ is the PDF of the parameter $\theta$ and $\Theta$ is the domain of $\theta$. Now, this itself is not very representative, since the slope, being negative or positive, can cancel out, so we add squaring, and arrive at the definition.

**Now, I don't understand how $I$ is a function and not a number (depending on our experiment result)- after we've taken the integral, $\theta$ must be gone. And, I also don't understand why is it that in the problems I am given in the class, I am given the distribution of $X_i$, and not of the parameter $\theta$.**

What are the mistakes and missing points in my reasoning?

Comment: Wikipedia article might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740898/qualitative-understanding-of-fisher-information.